# Is it possible to change an image (i.e. background) dynamically by using a variable in the URL?

Tags: html, wordpress, url

Example URL:
mydomain.com/?niche=*golfer*

This would switch the background to an image of a golfer like "golfer.png"

mydomain.com/?niche=*yoga*
This would switch the background to an image of a yoga studio like "yoga.png"

Does this make sense?
I've seen it done in custom software that is no longer supported.

If possible, is there a WordPress plugin you know of that can do the same?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I doubt a plugin would exist for specifically this purpose, however you could write a simple function for use in your templates and add it to your themes `functions.php` file or wrap it up as a plugin if preferred (more work).

Comment: Does anyone have an example of how this could be done? I'm pretty new at this, but I have a feeling it could be helpful for people trying to improve their sales funnels, etc. I know it's been done with a product called Bridge Pages, but the software is now defunct. Here is a video that better explains the concept: [link](https://vimeo.com/386894074/f08a32e871)